# i am getting AttributeError for python code

Tags: python-3.x

i am new to python, please help me with this problem i have created a tab widget and have button in tab widget,on clicking that button i need to display a new window/dialog containing 4 to 5 line edits but i am getting attribute error when calling method on button click please help me from this problem
this is my code

```
 class TabDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):
    super(TabDialog, self).__init__(parent)

    fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(fileName)

    tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    tabWidget.addTab(PatientTab(fileInfo), "Patient Info")
     ....
class NewWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    group1= QtGui.QGroupBox("Add Data")
    patientName = QtGui.QLabel("Name")
    patientEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    patientid = QtGui.QLabel("Id")
    patientidEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    genderlabel = QtGui.QLabel("Gender")
    patientgend = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    eyeType = QtGui.QLabel("Eye Type")
    eyeTypeEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    AddData = QtGui.QPushButton("Add Data")

            databaseLayout = QTGui.QGridLayout()
    databaseLayout.addWidget(patientName,0,0)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(patientEdit,0,1)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(patientid,1,0)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(patientidEdit,1,1)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(genderLabel,2,0)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(patientgend,2,1)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(eyeType,3,0)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(eyeTypeEdit,3,1)
        databaseLayout.addWidget(AddData,4,10)

        group1.setLayout(databaseLayout)

    mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(group1)
    mainLayout.addStretch(1)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)

class PatientTab(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self, fileInfo, parent=None):
    super(PatientTab, self).__init__(parent)

    self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QGroupBox()
    self.newButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
self.newButton.setText("New")
    ***self.newButton.clicked.connect(self.newButton_Clicked)
    .........
    self.newWindow = NewWindow(self)


def newButton_Clicked(self):
    self.newWindow.exec_()
```

the line started with *** is where i am getting error
AttributeError: 'PatientTab' object has no attribute 'newButton_Clicked'
where i am going wrong please help......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the indentation in your question the same as in your code?

It appears that your newButton_Clicked method is declared outside the scope of the PatientTab class.   That would be why your PatientTab does note have a self.newButton_Clicked attribute...

Comment: @darshankatari ... you're welcome.   The accepted way to say thanks is to accept the answer, and maybe vote it up ;)